# Not able to get the TreePanel working (with XML source) in Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs

I have a url which is returning me the below XML.

```
<system>
  <data x="1" y="2" z="3" /> 
  <data x="1" y="2" z="3" /> 
  <data x="1" y="2" z="3" /> 
  <data x="1" y="2" z="3" /> 
</system>
```

I want to load this XML in a tree panel. I am using TreeStore for this. But not getting success in this.

Can some one have any such example code, which is working in Ext Js 4.1.

Help will be really appreciated..!!

Comment: You need to show basic attempt to solve it yourself. Add examples of what you have tried and errors it produced.

Answer (score 0):

If you got your data in Objects already you can use something like that:

i assume your data looks like that in an object form:

```
data = [{x=1, y=2, z=3}, {x=1, y=2, z=3}, {x=1, y=2, z=3},{x=1, y=2, z=3}];
```

i would recommend to set the leaf attribute too if an item doesnt have any childs.

```
treestore.setRootNode({ root: true, expanded: true, children: data });
```

Useful links:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-setRootNode
and also have a look into the NodeInterface